# JQuery / Thymeleaf: overwriting submit action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I work in a Spring Boot application, where I have this property defined in the application.properties

```
server.contextPath=/NoEnTenimNiCinc
```

I want to overwrite the submit action in a Thymeleaf template, but I don't know how to set the context path

```
$('#geocodingButtonId').click(function(){       
        $('#deviceFormId').attr('action', /*[[@{/}]]*/ '/device/search');
});
```

I also tried

```
$('#geocodingButtonId').click(function(){       
     $('#deviceFormId').attr('action','/device/search');
});
```

I want the app to go

```
http://localhost:8080/NoEnTenimNiCinc/device/search/
```

but instead the apps goes to

```
http://localhost:8080/device/search/
```

Comment: just give the file name as a second parameter in attr

Comment: path is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
$('#geocodingButtonId').click(function(){
  var url = /*[[@{/device/search}]]*/ '';
  $('#deviceFormId').attr('action', url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
$('#geocodingButtonId').click(function(){       
     $('#deviceFormId').attr('action','device/search');
});
```

Comment: remove the first slash and try like this?

Comment: Did you try this? @Bruts